# Finding numbers in a text and summing them

Tags: java, regex

Seeking regex experts here. I have a string that has numbers in it such as

```
abc 2 de fdfg 3 4 fdfdfv juk  @  dfdfgd 45
```

I need to find all the numbers from such string and sum it up.

My Java code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = " abc 2 de fdfg 3 4 fdfdfv juk  @  dfdfgd 45";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w*\\W*(\\d*)]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Matched");

            // For loop is not executed since groupCount is zero
            for (int i=0; i<matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                String group = matcher.group(i);
                System.out.println(group);
            }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match");
    }
}
```

So matcher.matches() returns true, and therefore I can see that "Matched" getting printed. However, when I try to get the groups, expecting numbers, nothing gets printed.

Can someone please point to me what is wrong with my regex and grouping part?

Comment: You probably should look what `[..]` means in regex because your pattern doesn't do what you think: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Also you are misunderstanding `groupCount`. It doesn't return how many times regex can be applied, but how many groups exists in pattern.

Comment: @Pshemo Removing square bracket [] doesn't matches the pattern. It is required.

Comment: Who said anything about removing them? I just trying to point out that you are misusing them. Also you probably don't even need `matches` anyway but `find` (EDIT: which accepted answer confirms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the digits out in groups and not worry about the white spaces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = " abc 2 de fdfg 3 4 fdfdfv juk  @  dfdfgd 45";

    // "\\d+" will get all of the digits in the String
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

    int sum = 0;
    // Convert each find to an Integer and accumulate the total
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

Results:

> Sum: 54

Comment: This worked. I think I got to know the difference between matches() and find(). Selecting your response as an answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] arr=source.split("\\d+");
int sum=0;
for(String x : arr) {
  int n=0;
  try {
    n=Integer.parseInt(x);
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){}
  sum+=n;
}

System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
```